# How can akka actor interact between threads

Tags: multithreading, akka

I've read akka documentation and can't produce clean understanding of thread interaction while using akka. Docs may omit this thing as obvious but it is not so obvious for me.

All akka actors seemed to be run in same thread they are called. I see actors as co-procedures that just had own stack reset each time receive called.

You may perform a huge chain of actors switching in straight line. Each receive perform small non-blocking operation and force another receive to work further. There is no event loop, that can handle messages outside of the actor system.

I'd like to catch a request from other thread, perform control operations, and wait for another message.

There are some use cases that outline my needs.

1. There is thread that constantly polling data from some sources. Once data matches pattern it invokes event-driven handler based on actors. Logical controller makes a decision and passes it workers. There should be two persistent thread. One threads works constantly on polling and another works asynchronously to control it work. You should not let akka actors to first thread since they broke polling periods and first thread should not block actors so they need another thread.
2. There is some kind of two-side board game. One side has a controller thread that schedules calculation time works interacts with board server and etcetera. Other thread is a heavy calculating thread that loops over different variants and could not be written in akka since it has blocking nature

I aware of existing akka futures, but they represent a working task that run once fired and shutting down after performing their goal. The futures are well combined with akka actors, but can not express looped working threads.

Akka actor system incorporates different kinds of network event loops. You may use its built-in remote actor system or well known 0mq protocol. But using network for thread interactions seems like overdoing for me.

What is the supposed way to glue non-akka thread with akka one? Should I wrote a couple of special procedures to perform message passing in thread-safe way?

Comment: well, I don’t think we omit all that much: http://akka.io/docs/akka/2.0-RC4/scala/dispatchers.html

Comment: One more correction: akka actors do not run on the same thread they are called, see my previous comment for docs. Actors are not co-procedures. “Stack reset” is not a concept supported by the JVM. The actor model is a higher abstraction level than threads. Passing messages to an actor is always thread-safe (see `ActorRef.tell()`)

Comment: I suggest you checkout akka with apache camel integration for how to respond to external events. The book Akka Essentials http://www.packtpub.com/akka-java-applications-essentials/book has a clear description of the threading model with plenty of runnable sample code in both Java and Scala to get all the fundamentals.

Comment: simbo1905: I've found the most organic way to embed akka in other local threads: https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/2422443

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need polling, then the polling thread should just turn whatever is polled into a message and fire it off to an actor.

I find it more useful to use an Actor with a receiveTimeout to do non-blocking polling at an interval, and when there's something that gets polled, it will publish it to some other actor, or perhaps even its ActorSystems' EventStream, for true pub-sub action.

Comment: what thread the actor would be runned in? What is beneath an actor system, what threads are used by it to hold own activity?

Comment: In my case I'm using akka to control swing application with 3D viewer control. So I think about combining three different event loops without race conditions and blocks. I need more data about akka system structure to build right architecture.

Comment: I've read it several times (for new version of akka) and still miss thread architecture description.

Comment: If you tell me what a thread architecture description actually is, then I'll explain.

Comment: what thread actors are run in? If a message is fired on a thread, would it be handled in this one, or in separate? The simplest architecture need no thread support, actors are used as co-procedures in that thread they are issued, storing messages in special mailbox and than all needed actors are called in chain to response provided messages, until the queue becomes empty (if there is no loops anb blocks). Then as the first message were fired from outside of actor system, because actors are called by need, the actor system returns flow control to the point it was called.

Comment: the above way fits actors model completely but is very basic. You may use another approach: made a separate thread for actor processing (or may be a bunch of worker threads) and a thread-safe message firing method. In that case outside block that fired message to an actor system thread-safely transfers it to the queue and immediately resumes command flow. This way is more tricky and more flexible.

Comment: So, I should know what kind of thread work are concealed beneath actor system to adjust existing event loops for correct thread-safe working with akka

Comment: Actors (and Futures ..) are executed using an ExecutionContext (this is in the docs), the execution context is essentially a j.u.c.Executor, so it uses that to execute chunks of logic. Please read the docs section on "dispatchers" for more info around different implementations.

Comment: thank you a lot. The key is that Executor is java.util.concurrent.Executor. I come to akka from scala not java and scala books proclaim that with akka you have no need in java concurrency. How foolish I was to disregard it.

Comment: Which book which page, if I may ask?